# What's the best tool on Windows to rename CSS elements in both a CSS file as well as in multiple HTML files?

Tags: html, css, refactoring

I need to rename a large number of CSS elements in both the CSS file in which they are defined as well as in multiple HTML files in which they are used.

What's the best way to do this on Windows?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a ASP.NET developer, I know you can do this in Visual Studio using **Find and Replace in Files**. It's a huge application for this specific task, but has a multitude of other productivity features for HTML, CSS and other source code editing. Visual Studio Web Developer Express is freely available here: [http://www.microsoft.com/express/vwd](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vwd/)

Answer (score 0):

Usually more advanced code editors will support project wide find/replace, but there are plenty of freeware utilities that are only a google away. Take look at this one. I haven't used it personally, but looks like it will do the trick.

http://www.nirmaltv.com/2008/11/05/find-and-replace-from-multiple-files/

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio (and the free Express version) allows you to rename values across multiple files (from the keyboard, use Ctrl+Shift+H. There are other smaller tools out there but watch out for ASCII/Unicode encoding issues.